# android - another android UI question

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a scrollview ( mainly for landscape purposes, as I don't have a different xml file, I'm using android:configChanges="orientation")
which contains a RelativeLayout and within it there's a Linear Layout.

The code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:background="@color/background"
android:padding="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:textSize="24.5sp" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/time_window_please_select_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>

        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:prompt="@string/time_window_prompt" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px" android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:text="@string/start_label" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px" android:id="@+id/status_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px" android:id="@+id/status_time_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/info_button" android:src="@drawable/info"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Everything works fine, both in portrait and loandscape mode except for the ImgView (info_button) at the very end.
I used a Relative Layout because I thought I'd be able to position it on bottom right hand corner (a bit of margin would be desirable bottom and right) of the screen...

This is what I get instead...

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~am907/wrong.png

any help appreciated!

EDIT: The link to the full XML file http://pastebin.com/Cce4AC4v (for some reason I can't see it all in preview mode but it's there when I try to re-copy in the text form)

Thanks
andreas

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

Try:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Edit:  Reading your question again, I believe the problem is the `ScrollView`.  I'm not sure why you are using this type of layout.  You could get rid of it in favor of the relative layout and that should solve your problem.  I'm not sure why you feel this activity needs to support landscape.  If so, I would boil the `ScrollView` down to a single view object and try to troubleshoot that.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it only went to the right. It didn't go at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Show your full layout.  Your missing the top half.

Comment: here's a link for that http://pastebin.com/Cce4AC4v. I use scrollview for landscape mode. I can't have a seperate xml file because I use android:configChanges="orientation"

Answer (score 0):

I have understood that u want to place that image at bottom - right location. If so, then give:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/info_button" android:src="@drawable/info"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

If this is not the solution, could you place ur desired screen to be prepared, so that we can cross check ur layout.

Comment: Hi, I've already done that, as user432209 suggested but it takes it to the right of the "time remaining" textview but not the very bottom (not the bottom right corner of the screen). If I remove ScrollView entirely then my problem is solved. However I'd still like to be able to cater for when the user switches to landscape. What I want to achieve is as follows http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~am907/device.png with scroll view enabled (for landscape purposes). Without scrollview, in landscape half of the stuff are missing.